# What is the right way to throw an error message in NextJS 13.4 API? (Response, NextAPIResponse, NextResponse)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel, next.js13

Previously, throwing errors in the apis looked like this.

```
 if (error) {
      return response
      .status(500)
      .json({ error: 'Error getting data from Supabase' });
```

where the response was a NextAPIResponse object type.  This no longer works, what is the right way to do it now? (Assuming that you are using `app routing` and not `page routing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'm sure there are many ways to do it, the way that I'm following is the way that is documented in the NextJS docs [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-response).

In `Typescript` for clarity:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 })
}
```

and `Javascript` for those that prefer it:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
 
export async function GET(request) {
  return NextResponse.json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' }, { status: 500 })
}
```

Note: I have experimented with replacing the word `error` in { error: 'Internal Server Error' } with  {statusText:  'Internal Server Error' } since this is the default spec in the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/Response); also, when you console log the received object from your fetch in NextJS (ie. when you console log that which is returned from your API) that key `error` turns to `statusText`.  Either way has worked fine.